# save data to sql server with asp.net using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

After I entered the data, my ajax function did not run. That makes my code not work in "WebService2.asmx/ThemTaiKhoan" which makes my data unable to save to the database. Can someone help me, please? Thank you so much.Here is my code.  WebService2.asmx

```
public string ThemTaiKhoan(string username, string password, string fullname, string email, string dienthoai, string status, string admin)
    {

        string query = "insert into login values (" + username + ",'" + password + "'," + fullname + ",'" + email + "','" + dienthoai + "'," + status + ",'" + admin + "')";

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Appconnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Here is JS code on ThemMoi.aspx

```
<script>
    function ThemTaiKhoan() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var status = $("#status").val();
        var admin = $("#admin").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService2.asmx/ThemTaiKhoan",
            data: "{username:" + username + ",password:'" + password + "',fullname:" + fullname + ",email:'" + email + "',phone:'" + phone + "',status:" + status + ",admin:'" + admin + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (ms) {

                location.reload();

            },
            dataType: "json",
        })
    }
</script>
```

Here is HTML code on ThemMoi.aspx

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Nhập thông tin tài khoản</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Tên đăng nhập:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Mật khẩu:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fullname">Tên đầy đủ:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Fullname" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Điện thoại:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Trạng thái:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" placeholder="Status" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="admin">Admin:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="admin" placeholder="Admin" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Thêm" onclick="ThemTaiKhoan()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="TrangChu.aspx">Trang chủ</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is the result when I debug in chrome, the code doesn't work inside the ajax function. What happened? :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae0Lk.png)

Comment: You seem to be missing `;` at the end of '$.ajax`.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Remember to parameterize your queries or little bobby tables will haunt you! https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"username" : username, "fullname" : fullname, "email" : email, "phone" : phone, "status" : status, "admin" : admin})
```

Answer (score 0):

Decorate with [WebMethod]  attribute which is missing in your code..

```
[WebMethod]  
public string ThemTaiKhoan(string username, string password, string 
fullname, string email, string dienthoai, string status, string admin)
    {

        string query = "insert into login values (" + username + ",'" + password + "'," + fullname + ",'" + email + "','" + dienthoai + "'," + status + ",'" + admin + "')";

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Appconnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Edit: you are missing single quotes in your json string. Please use below code for data

```
  data: "{username:'" + username + "',password:'" + password + "',fullname:'" + fullname + "',email:'" + email + "',phone:'" + phone + "',status:'" + status + "',admin:'" + admin + "'}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your data option. It should be formated like below:

```
data: {'username:' + username} and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include error in ajax call and debug this.

```
success: function (ms) {
    location.reload();
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
     debugger;
     console.log(errorThrow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send data in this format

```
data: "{ 'username ': '" + username + "','password': '" + password+ "', 'fullname': '" + fullname+ "','email':'" + email+ "'}",
```

or use this way to make your code more organized and clear

```
    <script>
    function ThemTaiKhoan() {
        var adminInfo= {

        username = $("#username").val();
        password = $("#password").val();
        fullname = $("#fullname").val();
        email    = $("#email").val();
        phone    = $("#phone").val();
        status   = $("#status").val();
        admin    = $("#admin").val();
       };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService2.asmx/ThemTaiKhoan",
        data: adminInfo,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (ms) {

            location.reload();

        },
        dataType: "json",
    })
}
```

//cotrolercode

```
public class adminInfo
{
   public string username;
   public string password;
   public string fullname;
   public string email;
   public string dienthoai;
   public string status;
   public string admin;
}
   public string ThemTaiKhoan(adminInfo adminIfo)
{

    string query = "insert into login values (" + adminIfo.username + ",'" + adminIfo.password + "'," + adminIfo.fullname + ",'" + adminIfo.email + "','" + adminIfo.dienthoai + "'," + adminIfo.status + ",'" + adminIfo.admin + "')";

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Appconnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return query;
}
```